# How to create jar file for ANE in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, artifact

I use Eclipse for Java that works well and for AS3 use IntelliJ that is much better. But IntelliJ do not know create working jar file for ANE.

Does anyone know how to set the project/artifact in IntelliJ for correct and working jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some days experimenting is here my solution https://github.com/Abedron/ANE-ImagePicker